# Alternatives to Apache tika

Tags: android

I needed to extract metadata from chm, rtf, doc/docx, odf, djvu and mobi. 
I tried using Apache Tika and spend more than 3 days to make work on Android to no avail. 
Is there any library which I you know that I can use to extract meta-data from the afore mentioned files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [FolioReader](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android) they seem to be doing some things you want, and its open source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it only supports epub.